How to turn off backpressure in Aeron IPC
How do I turn off backpressure in intrabox communications on Aeron?
I want to disconnect the slow clients so the publisher can keep running at max speeds.

This can be controlled with tethering.
https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/wiki/Flow-And-Congestion-Control#subscription-tethering
